# Merge above and below rows in DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, rows

I have a dataframe, but I need to perform some cleaning, in some cases the values from above and below rows in column "Code" are separated, is there any way to merge these rows? df - is what I have, and df1 what I need to have (the values can be both in numeric and string format).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 


df = pd.DataFrame({"DT":[np.nan,65,np.nan, 65,45,np.nan,34,np.nan],
      "Code":[56,np.nan,"TD","TR",52,1,np.nan,76],
      "DV":[np.nan,"CAT",np.nan,"B54","T65",np.nan,765,np.nan],
      "GT":[np.nan,76,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,65,np.nan]})


df1 = pd.DataFrame({"DT":[65,65,45,34],
      "Code":["56 TD","TR",52,"1 76"],
      "DV":["CAT","B54","T65",765],
      "GT":[76,np.nan,np.nan,65]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

Original dataset (df):

```
     DT Code   DV    GT
0   NaN   56  NaN   NaN
1  65.0  NaN  CAT  76.0
2   NaN   TD  NaN   NaN
3  65.0   TR  B54   NaN
4  45.0   52  T65   NaN
5   NaN    1  NaN   NaN
6  34.0  NaN  765  65.0
7   NaN   76  NaN   NaN
```

Code:

```
df['temp1']=df['Code'].shift()
df['temp2']=df['Code'].shift(-1)
df['temp1']=df['temp1'].fillna('')
df['temp2']=df['temp2'].fillna('')
df['temp1']=df['temp1'].astype(str)
df['temp2']=df['temp2'].astype(str)
df['Code']=np.where(df['Code'].isna(), df['temp1']+' '+df['temp2'], df['Code'])
df['temp1']=df['temp1'].replace('', np.nan)
df['temp2']=df['temp2'].replace('', np.nan)
df.dropna(subset=['temp1', 'temp2'], how='any', inplace=True)
df.drop(['temp1', 'temp2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df['DT']=df['DT'].astype(int)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   DT   Code   DV    GT
0  65  56 TD  CAT  76.0
1  65     TR  B54   NaN
2  45     52  T65   NaN
3  34   1 76  765  65.0
```

Comment: Thank you very nice solution!

Comment: Welcome, happy to help!